# Is there a way to get Flamenco Manager to always spin up under the same local IP address each time?

Tags: network

[image]
Rendering with Flamenco 3.2 has been great but when a session is finished or we have to restart it, the IP address almost always changes.  So then you have to go and edit preferences and update the IP so the Blender project sees it again.  You also have to change the IP in the browser.

I thought there would be a way to simply force the IP address to something we define in the flamenco-manager.yaml but nothing seems to work.  Not a major inconvenience compared to the time Flamenco saves, but this is not the most efficient work flow.

Ideally, I'd be able to set up in etc/hosts a http://flamenco.loc mapped to this static IP, but not if the Flamenco Manager decides to seemingly randomly change to a new IP address each time.

Does anyone know how to force Flamenco Manager to always remain at the same IP or some other trick?

I am currently on Windows 10 machine, using Blender 3.6.2 with Flamenco 3.2.

Comment: I guess this is a question for Flamenco developers rather than about using Blender itself.

Comment: Thanks @GordonBrinkmann, I do see other network related questions in this stack but I think you're right, I'll go ask the Blender team as well! https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=network

Comment: Yes, but if there is not a simple setting for that which you probably already would have found, this might be a more in-depth question for developers, and since this site is run by volunteers and we are no developers or in any way affiliated with the Blender organization this site is probably the wrong place to look for answers. Here we are focusing on problems with the regular usage of Blender tools.

Comment: Echoing what Gordon said, not sure if many users on here are familiar with Flamenco enough to answer this. I think this question should be left open but id encourage asking flamenco people directly https://flamenco.blender.org/development/get-involved/

All that said though, how is this ip address obtained? Perhaps its not up to flamenco to set it, if it's through dhcp or something is it possible you might have to create a rule in your network router?

Comment: Thanks @gandalf3, good question as to how it is set.  I don't think it's through DHCP though.  It appears to be programmatic in the Flamenco plugin where it looks for an IP that's available without any logical pattern that I can find.  It's currently 192.1.168.106:8080. I will close Blender and reopen and it will be 192.1.168.154:8080 the next time, etc.